# Chrome does not play a video file but play it with dragging file into Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video

I have a video file with MP4 format and H264 encode. Mozilla play this video without any problem. but Chrome cannot play it. but when i drag video file in Chrome tab, Chrome play that video file! any idea?

```html
<video controls poster="~/Content/img/blog/350x200/03374127-68b9-4846-8f9f-e514b2c2f01d.jpg" preload="none">
   <source src="@Url.Content("/Content/file/Clip01_Final.mp4")" type="video/mp4">Does not sup..
</video>
```

Comment: Just tested, this does work on my machine, when i direct linked the video and poster. It may be because your video file is not properly accessible, either the path has problems or it is served as a octet stream, which is used for downloads instead of direct viewing in a browser.

Comment: Is the output HTML URL from the `<source>` a `file://` link? I'm pretty sure such url's almost never work. always try running a local apache installation with a configured hostname for development environments